# Dynamically add eventtocommand actions to a listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a page with

namespaces:

```
xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP7"
```

xaml at design time:

```
<ListBox  x:Name="ItemGroupsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemGroups}" Height="496" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
         <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
             <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                     x:Name="SelectionChangedEvent" 
                     Command="{Binding GoToEditItemGroupCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </Custom:EventTrigger>
    </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the code, I am generating multiple listboxes at run time and would like to be able to bind to a relaycommand on the viewmode like the above xaml code shown above...

How do I do the above at run time in the code behind of the view.

Also, I would like to assign the datacontext for the dynamically generated listboxes to different view models than the one currently bound to my view.

Basically, I have a panaroma and with each panaroma items being created dynamically with each panaroma item having a listbox that will be bound to a viewmodel with relaycommands

Comment: <ListBox  x:Name="ItemGroupsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemGroups}" Height="496" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                        <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectionChangedEvent" Command="{Binding GoToEditItemGroupCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                            </Custom:EventTrigger>
                        </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>

Comment: you need to prefix code with 4 spaces. And is it Silverlight or WPF we are talking about?

Comment: This is a wp7 silverlight 3 application. Sorry, I should have mentioned that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: See also [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500650/static-and-dynamic-panorama-items-in-a-panorama-wp7-mvvm/6541331#6541331).**

[This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/SilverBlog/archive/2009/09/22/behaviors-how-to-attach-behavior-in-code-behind-silverlight-3.aspx) describes how you can attach behaviours from code behind.

**However**, I firmly would not advise you to go down this route unless you have a **compelling** need to do so. If you use this approach in your `ViewModel`, you will loose all testability as it generates a `ViewModel` that is highly coupled to the `View`, and in fact cannot live without it. (*Side note:* for this reason it is also not good practise to return the event args to the `ViewModel` use `CommandParameter` instead to return the `DataContext` if needed).

Normally you can archive your goal using MVVM in another manner, and the rest of the post describes this.

First, you do not need to use a `Command` to get the selected property, nor to get the notification that this property has changed. The usual pattern for this is that you bind the `SelectedItem` of your list box to a property in your `ViewModel`. Now you can use the `PropertyChanged` event to track when this property changed.

Second, use templates to generate and style your listboxes. When you need to only show them when the item is selected use a `BooleanToVisibility` ([Sample see here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2011/02/booleantovisibilityconverter.html) converter and bind the sub-listboxes' `Visibility` property to a property on your `ViewModel` using the converter (not my the sample).

The sample creates a ListBox that has its `ItemsSource` bound to the Items property of the `ViewModel`. It further creates a `ContentControl` that has its `DataContext` bound to the `SelectedItem` of the `ViewModel`. The `ContentControl` then contains again a `ListBox` where the `DataContext` is bound to the `SubItem` property of the `ItemViewModel`. The `MainViewModel` generates test data to be shown at design time and run time.

The rest of the post shows an sample:

**1. XAML of main page (except):**

```
        <ContentControl x:Name="target1" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}" Margin="20,0">
            <ContentControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name:" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Background="navy" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Template>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**2. The Main View Model**

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // working with fields to ensure no events are fired during initial phase
        this._items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            var item = new ItemViewModel() { Name = string.Format("Item {0}", i) };
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                item.SubItems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Name = string.Format("{0} - Sub Item {1}", item.Name, j) });
            this._items.Add(item);
        }
        this.SelectedItem = this._items[0];

        if (IsInDesignMode) {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        } else {
            // Code runs "for real"
        }
    }

    #region [Items]

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Items" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";

    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items = default(ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Items property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items {
        get {
            return _items;
        }

        set {
            if (_items == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _items;
            _items = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName);

            // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
            //RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [SelectedItem]

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedItem" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SelectedItemPropertyName = "SelectedItem";

    private ItemViewModel _selectedItem = default(ItemViewModel);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the SelectedItem property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem {
        get {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set {
            if (_selectedItem == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _selectedItem;
            _selectedItem = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedItemPropertyName);

            // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
            //RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedItemPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**3. The ItemView Model**

public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region [Name]

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Name" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string NamePropertyName = "Name";

    private string _name = default(string);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Name property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name {
        get {
            return _name;
        }

        set {
            if (_name == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _name;
            _name = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);

            // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
            //RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [SubItems]

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SubItems" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SubItemsPropertyName = "SubItems";

    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _myProperty = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the SubItems property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> SubItems {
        get {
            return _myProperty;
        }

        set {
            if (_myProperty == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _myProperty;
            _myProperty = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            RaisePropertyChanged(SubItemsPropertyName);

            // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
            //RaisePropertyChanged(SubItemsPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Edit 2**

The templating of the `Panorama` control can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500650/static-and-dynamic-panorama-items-in-a-panorama-wp7-mvvm).

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. I have more questions. I have one panaroma item in wp7 for which the data is being bound at design item. The rest of the panaroma items are being generated at run time and bound to view models at run time.. I would like to do that cleanly at design time declaratively in xaml..

Comment: How do i define a datatemplate for a panorama item and set the data context for that panorama items to my view model collection at run time. This code doesn't work       foreach (Model.LocationGroup group in viewModel.LocationGroups)
            {
                if (group.TotalItems > 0)
                {
                    PanoramaItem pi = new PanoramaItem();
                    pi.Header = group.Name;
                    pi.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
                    ItemLocationListViewModel itemLocationViewModel = viewModel[group.LocationGro