# Static and dynamic panorama items in a panorama wp7 mvvm

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

Here is my situation.

```
ViewModelA {  
    ObservableCollection<Items> ItemsA  
    ObservableCollection<ViewModelB> ViewModelBs
}
```

View A with the datacontext set to ViewModel A
ViewA has a panorama with a listbox, panels, textblocks etc with the items source for the listbox bound to ItemsA

I want to add other panorama items at runtime to the panorama control with a commond data template (listbox, textblock...etc).. Each panorama item will be bound at run time to each ViewModelB in the ViewModelBs collection.

I am not oppose to doing some codebehind stuff for this as I am not a strict mvvm purist..
but the solution could be elegant if I could specify control and data templates and make this work. I am kind of new to wpf/xaml and trying to break in to those technologies by writing a wp7 app.. using the mvvm light framework.. Eventually, i want my dynamically generated panorama items/list box content fire off relay commands on the viewmodel they are being bound to...

Here is some code snippet that i tried unsuccessfully to work. Hope it provides some idea..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PanoramaItemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                        <controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="ItemLocationPanoramaItem" Header="{Binding TagName}">
                            <StackPanel >
                                <ListBox  x:Name="ItemLocatorsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemLocators}" Height="496" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemLocation, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                    <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectionChangedEvent" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=DataContext.GoToEditItemLocatorCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                        </Custom:EventTrigger>
                                    </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel> 
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                                        <StackPanel Width="311">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Location.Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </StackPanel> 
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </controls:PanoramaItem>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style> 
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Codebehind:
    private LocationGroupsViewModel viewModel = null;

```
    public LocationGroups()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        LocationGroupsPanaroma.DefaultItem = LocationGroupsPanaroma.Items[0];
         viewModel = this.DataContext as LocationGroupsViewModel;
         CreateDynamicPanaromaItems();
    }


    private void CreateDynamicPanaromaItems()
    {
        foreach (Model.LocationGroup group in viewModel.LocationGroups)
        {
            if (group.TotalItems > 0)
            {
                PanoramaItem pi = new PanoramaItem();
                pi.Header = group.Name;
                pi.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
                ItemLocationListViewModel itemLocationViewModel = viewModel[group.LocationGroupId];
                pi.DataContext = itemLocationViewModel;
                pi.Style = Resources["PanoramaItemStyle"] as Style;
                LocationGroupsPanaroma.Items.Add(pi);

            }
        }

    }
```

Edit

ViewModel A has

```
Items collection

Collection of ViewModelBs
```

panaroma data context set to viewmodelA

```
panaroma item - Statitically created in xaml to some Items collection in ViewModelA

    This pan item has a list box



panaroma items --- to be bound to collection of viewmodelbs

    These pan items should each have a listbox which is selectable
                  and  bound to some collection in View Model B and fires commands on    selection         changed to viewModelB. Currently using the galasoft eventtocommand to hook the selection changed on the
    list box to a relay command. The problem is that this eventtommand should have the viewmodel as its data context and the not the collection (bound to the listbox) within viewmodel.
```

Comment: I can get this to work by using a style but the event to commands doesn't seem to work within a style any more. It appears i need to change the data context in the binding to my parent view model.. tried a few things and could not get it to work                      Need this to fire  <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectionChangedEvent" Command="{Binding GoToEditLocationGroupCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
 >

Comment: Please note that stack overflow is a site that helps you find the solution yourself by pointing you in the right direction. It is not a site that solves concrete programming tasks. I.e. it is a tool for learning! You already posted a nearly identical question and usually - if the answer does not quite fit your problem - you edit your original post, clearly marking the edit. The more information in the post the more likely you will get a suitable answer. On the subject I will have a look at how you can solve the problem with templates - but I

Comment: @obalix I am not expecting concrete solutions.. I understand the purpose. Kind of new to stackoverflow and did not know.. i could edit the original post.... :-)

Answer (score 3):

OK, finally got time to answer the question. The proposed solution does not require any code behind and only relys on MVVM concepts and data binding.

Conceptionally the `Panorama` control is an ItemPresenter (it inherits from `ItemsPresenter`), i.e. you can bind the `ItemsSource` to a list that contains items that repesent your `PanoramaItems`.

To render your `PanoramaItem` you will have to provide templates for `Panorama.HeaderTemplate` and `Panorama.ItemTemplate`. The `DataContext` inside the templates is the `ViewModel` that represents your `PanoramaItem`. If this `ViewModel` contains an item list you now can use it to generate the `ListBoxes` you were looking for.

And here is the sample ...

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace WP7Test.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static MainViewModel _main;

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic) {
        // Create design time services and viewmodels
    } else {
        // Create run time services and view models
    }
            _main = new MainViewModel();
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return _main;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        if (IsInDesignMode) {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        } else {
            // Code runs "for real"
        }
        this.LoadData();
    }

    #region [Items]

    public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";

    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items = default(ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>);

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items {
        get {
            return _items;
        }
        private set {
            if (_items == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _items;
            _items = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void LoadData() {
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime one", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime two", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime three", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent" });

        foreach (var item in Items) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                item.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "Item " + i, LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" });
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemViewModel.cs**

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ItemViewModel() {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        if (IsInDesignMode) {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        } else {
            // Code runs "for real": Connect to service, etc...
        }
    }

    public override void Cleanup() {
        // Clean own resources if needed

        base.Cleanup();
    }

    #region [LineOne]

    public const string LineOnePropertyName = "LineOne";

    private string _lineOne = default(string);

    public string LineOne {
        get {
            return _lineOne;
        }

        set {
            if (_lineOne == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _lineOne;
            _lineOne = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(LineOnePropertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [LineTwo]

    public const string LineTwoPropertyName = "LineTwo";

    private string _lineTwo = default(string);

    public string LineTwo {
        get {
            return _lineTwo;
        }

        set {
            if (_lineTwo == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _lineTwo;
            _lineTwo = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(LineTwoPropertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [LineThree]

    public const string LineThreePropertyName = "LineThree";

    private string _lineThree = default(string);

    public string LineThree {
        get {
            return _lineThree;
        }

        set {
            if (_lineThree == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _lineThree;
            _lineThree = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(LineThreePropertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Items]

    public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";

    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items = default(ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>);

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items {
        get {
            return _items;
        }
        private set {
            if (_items == value) {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _items;
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="WP7Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <controls:Panorama Title="my application" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>
            <controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
            <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" FontSize="28" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="0,20" BorderBrush="White">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" FontSize="24"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" FontSize="18" Margin="24,0,0,5"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama>
    </Grid>
    <!--Panorama-based applications should not show an ApplicationBar-->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**Edit - adding additional first panel**

Finally I understand what you trying to achive! However, you still need no code behind to do it! You just need a template ... for this Blend does help you as it lets you extract a template for a exiting control ... ok, here are the changes.

First I added a new property to the MainViewModel to show some data:

```
#region [MainPageProperty]

public const string MainPagePropertyPropertyName = "MainPageProperty";
private string _mainPageProperty = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu";

public string MainPageProperty {
    get {
        return _mainPageProperty;
    }
    set {
        if (_mainPageProperty == value) {
            return;
        }

        _mainPageProperty = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(MainPagePropertyPropertyName);
    }
}

#endregion
```

Then I used Blend to get the template for the Panorama control and inserted it into the `controls:Panorama` element.

```
<controls:Panorama.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Panorama">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <controlsPrimitives:PanningBackgroundLayer x:Name="BackgroundLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Border x:Name="background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
            </controlsPrimitives:PanningBackgroundLayer>
            <controlsPrimitives:PanningTitleLayer x:Name="TitleLayer" CacheMode="BitmapCache" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontSize="187" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,-76,0,9" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <controlsPrimitives:PanningLayer x:Name="ItemsLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Main panel" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.MainPageProperty}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </controls:PanoramaItem>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="items"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </controlsPrimitives:PanningLayer>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</controls:Panorama.Template>
```

There are two tricks here, first I inserted a StacPanel to have allow for more than one element underneath the `controlPrimitives:PanningLayer` with the name `ItemsPanel`. Into this `StackPanel` I moved the `ItemsPresenter` and added another `PanoramaItem`. One thing that is important, though, is to set the `Width` property of the `PanoramaItem`, as otherwise the panel will extend to the room that is needed.

The other trick is that in order to get access to the `DataContext` I had to use the `ElementName` in the Binding.

**Hope this shows the power of MVVM and Templating!**

Comment: The problem is that i want one panaroma item take data from ItemsA in ViewModelA and for other panaroma items, i am setting the datacontext to viewmodelb. The solution you have suggested works only if the panaroma is bound to a single view model. I want to have one pan item bound (statically bound to viewmodelA) and other pan items bound dynamically to observablecollection of viewmodelBs. I used a style & control template and with some code behind, I am able to get it work. The problem is that I have galasoft eventtocommand not working within control template.

Comment: I edited the main post with my new code. The problem is that i want the change the data context to parent for the code below. I tried a few things and doesn't work.   <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectionChangedEvent" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=DataContext.GoToEditItemLocatorCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>

Comment: See edit, this adds another PanoramaItem befor the list of PanoramaItems is built.

Comment: Can you post the xaml? I am diving into xaml through wp7 app. I tried a few ways to get the parent context for the galasoft event to command within the list box in the pan item. The element name binding doesn't seem to work

Comment: ViewModel A has
 
 Items collection
 
 Collection of ViewModelBs

panaroma data context set to viewmodelA 

 panaroma item - Statitically created in xaml to some Items collection in ViewModelA
   
  This pan item has a list box



 panaroma items --- to be bound to collection of viewmodelbs
  
  These pan items should each have a listbox which is selectable
  and fires commands on selection changed to viewModelB. Currently they
  are using the galasoft eventtocommand to hook the selection changed on the
  list box to a relay command

Comment: I don't like the way my comments end up on stackoverflow.. so i edited the main post with my scenario..

Comment: XAML was there but formatted wrongly, sorry. Fixed now. And comments are for commenting and answers for answering. Putting comments in the answer section might earn you bad reputation (minus-points).